# "referred to as" vs. "called"

Tags: grammar

In a sentence, is it better to use

*referred to as sth.*

or

*called sth.*

In the sentence I'm talking about TLS which is:

*most frequently **referred to as** SSL*

or

*most frequently **called** SSL*

I know both are correct, but I don't know which one is used in a modern, everyday talk.

Comment: Do you mean TLS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are used. 'referred to as' is slightly more formal, or rather is likely not to be used in informal contexts ('called' works in both contexts well).

> The queen is called 'her majesty' in her presence, don't you know.

and

> The gardner is called 'cheesecutter' to his face, innit.

Comment: Love the second example